# Solve the second order differential equation $y''y^3=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble solving the differential equation $y''y^3=1$.

Usual method is, since there is no $x$ in the equation to use the substitution $y'=p$. We can write $$y'' = \frac{dp}{dx} = \frac{dp}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {dp}{dy} p$$

The equation becomes:

$$py^3 \frac{dp}{dy}=1 \iff \int{p dp} = \int{\frac{dy}{y^3}}$$

$$p^2 = -\frac{1}{y^2}$$

Now if we could just take square root, the equation would be separable and we are done, but the solution that is given: $A y^2 = 1 + (Ax+B)^2$ is not of complex form. Perhaps the given solution is wrong or I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Forgot the constant changes things.With that it becomes $y'=\frac{\sqrt{2C y^2-1}}{y}$ which is simple integration.

Comment: Can you solve it now? It has become a separable equation.